# How to beautify/change style in a c++ project using clang/clang-tidy?

Tags: c++, clang, refactoring, clang-format, clang-tidy

Having a large c++ project I would like to change some styles.

I am currently wondering if changing the public class methods from camelCase to PascalCase is actually possible without having to write a full refactoring tool.
eg:

```
class MyLovelyClassPlentyOfCamelCaseMethods
{
    public:
        void aCamelCaseMethodIWouldLoveToConvertToPascalCaseEverywhere();
    protected:
    private:
        void anotherCamelCaseMethodIWouldLoveToRemainAsIs();
};
```

I know that LLVM/clang tools are a high powerful tools that can be oriented to achieve this but I am completely new at clang and clang-tidy in every aspect so any step by step guiding through is greatly welcomed. I have found several resources and documentation about but still couldn't reach to any useful point and started being really confused on how to go along with this.

Thanks a lot to the community in advance!

Comment: Use your IDE for refactoring, not the compiler. Here are some quick results for popular IDEs ([VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/refactoring-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019), [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring), [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/refactoring-source-code.html)).

Comment: @Frank Generally this is the correct recommendation, but clang-format is unable to make the specific change OP mentions. I have less experience with clang-tidy, but it might be capable with a custom rule. Otherwise this might be something better left to the IDE or a search and replace.

Comment: Thanks again for your comments and helps! I really appreciate it. Sadly I would like avoiding manual changes, even if they are mostly automatic and supported behind the VS refactor and multiple extensions that can be used.
The amount of changes required are even that much that I think it can probably worth building up a custom refactor tool...in that case will also need some experienced person advice.

Answer (score 1):

There is a clang-tidy check designed for this purpose :

[readability-identifier-naming](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/readability-identifier-naming.html)

Using the `fix` option you can use this check to actually convert the case from pascal to camel.

`readability-identifier-naming` can be used to convert case individually for different categories of identifiers.

To change case of public member methods to pascal* and private member methods to camel* your `.clang-tidy` file should look like this:

```
Checks: '-*,readability-identifier-naming'
CheckOptions:
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.PublicMethodCase, value: CamelCase}
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.PrivateMethodCase, value: camelBack}
```

*note: what you refer to as pascal case is called CamelCase and your camel case is camelBack in `clang-tidy`

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. But this actually doesn't help too much to find the way through to achieve the target goal of my question.

Comment: From other side there are many codestyles and there can be many different reasons why someone may decide to use the selected codestyle I mentioned on the question, so to me there is no point on blaming on a mix of pascal and camelcase style and less through words like "that way". Should there be a proper way to mix them? In that case please elaborate.

Comment: In my opinion they should not be mixed at all for the same category of symbols (like methods in a class in your question). You can have a coding style that suits you but from readability standpoint it pays off to keep the style simple and be consistent.

Comment: Methods inside a class have different categories also too from my readability standpoint a public method is not the same as a protected or private. Same for variables. But there is nothing more subjective than code style, there are many valid and plausible combinations. The important thing for a developer is to know how to adapt and understand each code style.

Comment: Ok I just realized I misunderstood your question - I apologize. I thought you wanted to arbitrarily choose which method should have what case because you didn't specify explicitly that the difference is the access specifier. Choosing different cases for public/private methods is supported in clang-tidy. Edited my answer accordingly.